# Метод добавления элемента в дерево

Tags: c++, дерево

Какой самый оптимальный вариант добавления элементов в бинарное дерево поиска на c++? Есть два вот таких кода.
Цикл:

```
void add_node(int value) {

    Node* rRoot = &this->root;

    Node* node = new Node;
    node->memory = value;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;

    while (true) {

        if (value < rRoot->memory) {
            if (rRoot->left == NULL) {
                rRoot->left = node;
                break;
            }
            else {
                rRoot = rRoot->left;
            }
        } else if (value > rRoot->memory) {
            if (rRoot->right == NULL) {
                rRoot->right = node;
                break;
            }
            else {
                rRoot = rRoot->right;
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Рекурсия:

```
struct tnode * addnode(int x, tnode *tree) {
  if (tree == NULL) { // Если дерева нет, то формируем корень
    tree =new tnode; // память под узел
    tree->field = x;   // поле данных
    tree->left =  NULL;
    tree->right = NULL; // ветви инициализируем пустотой
  }else  if (x < tree->field)   // условие добавление левого потомка
    tree->left = addnode(x,tree->left);
  else    // условие добавление правого потомка
    tree->right = addnode(x,tree->right);
  return(tree);
}
```

И теперь хочу узнать, как лучше добавлять элементы? Рекурсией или циклом? Циклом я сделал также потому, что меня очень смущает постоянное ПЕРЕприсваивание результата функции:

> tree->left = addnode(x,tree->left);

что, по сути, бесполезно (имеет смысл лишь в конце, когда дойдем до пустого узла).

P.S. Также буду рад любым другим хорошим примерам/фишкам, чтобы в них разобраться.

Comment: Итерация д.б. быстрее. / Кстати, у вас немного разные алгоритмы. В рекурсивной версии, при равенстве, вы идете по правой ветке, а в итеративной выходите из посмотра дерева (что делаете далее у вас не написано).

Comment: Что значит выхожу из просмотра? Я там иду по левой ветке, пока не встречу нулевое значение и на его место уже помещаю новый узел. В рекурсии тоже иду по левой ветке, если элемент меньше, чем подкорень. 

И так и не понял, то есть цикл будет работать быстрее? Не совсем понял, что значит итерация д.б.

Comment: Да, итерация это цикл. Он быстрее, т.к. не нужно запоминать адреса возврата в стеке. В своем цикле вы сравниваете `if (value < ...) go_left; else if (value > ...) go_right; else break // тут равно`, а в рекурсии `if (value < ...) go_left; else go_right; // тут больше или равно`. Т.о. в итерации вы отбросите (если приведен законченный фрагмент кода) элемент, который уже есть в дереве, а в рекурсии добавите его в правое поддерево.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо) Да, я специально в цикле отбрасываю равный элемент, чтобы дерево содержало только уникальные элементы.

Comment: Кстати какой вообще тогда смысл от рекурсии, если она не только медленная, но еще и есть риск переполнения стека?

Comment: Некоторые алгоритмы обработки дерева  компактнее (и смотрятся более естественно) в рекурсивном виде. Но вы верно догадались, при *правильном программировании* (это когда вы в самом деле понимаете, что именно вам надо получить) глубокого смысла в рекурсии нет